# what does "act the part" mean?

Tags: meaning

I can't fully understand what does " act the part" mean? And I want to find some example about this phrase. Can you help me and tell me the meaning and give me some example about it?

Comment: [literally the first link on google search for `act the part`](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dress-look-act-the-part)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please note: you should always state what you found in your own research or what you _think_ the phrase might mean. Find more about this on [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: In addition, "act the part" can have different meanings depending on how it is used; depending on which part you are acting.

Answer (score 1):

In this phrase, "the part" means a role as played by an actor.  For instance, someone might play the part of "Juliet" in Shakespeare's *Romeo and Juliet*.

To "act" the part means to perform the role, by reciting lines correctly and expressing the correct emotions.  For instance, someone acting the part of Juliet needs to appear deeply in love with Romeo.

Often, this phrase is used as a metaphor, to refer to someone who is pretending to be someone else and fully embracing the deception. For instance, someone who is meeting their girlfriend's parents might conceal bad habits and controversial opinions to "act the part" of a perfect boyfriend.